# Можно ли добавить ссылку "google.com" в Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ссылки, label

Можно ли из `label` с текстом **`"google.com"`** сделать активную ссылку?

```
root = Tk()
label = Label(text="google.com")
label.pack() 

mainloop()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to create a hyperlink with a Label in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482748/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-with-a-label-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"http://www.google.com")

root  = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="google.com", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
label.pack()
label.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ввот так лучше! И портируемо

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

class LinkLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self,parent, *argv, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.url = kwargs.pop('url')
        except:
            raise ValueError('No parameter url!')
        try:
            font = kwargs.pop('font')
            if font.__class__.__name__ == 'str':
                font = tuple(font.split())
            font_res = list(font)
            font_res.append('underline')
            font_res = tuple(set(font_res))
        except:
            font_res = ('arial',10,'underline')
        super().__init__(parent,*argv, font=font_res, fg='blue', cursor='hand2', **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.open_url)
    def open_url(self,event=None):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(self.url)
        self.config(fg = 'purple')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = tk.Tk()
    LinkLabel(a, text='linklabel', url = 'https://google.com').pack()
    a.mainloop()
```